# Google Play Vs In-App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-pay

So I'm planning to create an app that licenses and sells original photos in my android app where as users can directly purchase from other user these items and get a direct link from the app after purchase, the users who purchase another user's photo can upload the photo into other apps like IG/FB/Twitter/etc. As per google pay SECTION 2: Permissible Payment Transactions [Terms of Service](https://payments.developers.google.com/terms/sellertos) I cannot use Google pay to sell digital goods....however in-app billing is only for digital content limited to the scope of my app...can someone please clarify what the hell is going on with google ?

Comment: On this Google page (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing overview) it is written: "Google Play Billing can be used to sell two types of in-app products:

One-time products: an in-app product requiring a single, non-recurring charge to the user's form of payment. Additional game levels, premium loot boxes, or media files, are examples of one-time products. The Google Play Console refers to one-time products as "managed products", and the Google Play Billing library specifies one-time products as "INAPP"." they wrote" OR MEDIA FILES" so I think you could use in-app bill.

Comment: @emandt got it mate, I researched the both options because I didn't want to start on one and then have the behemoth that is google unpublish and possibly take legal action. Do things smart the first time and almost no repeats in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, like what you have mentioned above, In-app billing is only limited to your app, if you allow the user to use the digital photo outside of your app, it is not allow.

Comment: I talked to both of their support teams and they both agreed that in-app billing is the method for the type of content I am trying to sell, even if it has use-cases outside of the bounds of my app

Comment: @Alyosha_Karamazov It seems from this answer that since these photos can be used outside your app, you should not use Google Play for billing. What was their reason that you had to use Google Play for this?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at Google **Pay** ToS, which is not designed for mobile in-app purchases. For in-app purchases, you will be using Google **Play** Billing (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: there is a lot of ambiguity because  an app can potentially sell intangible assets. Things like GoodWills, Patents, etc. If these Intagible Assets will be procured from said app, the scope of in-app billing is arguably inapplicable because the aforementioned Intangible asset's value reach beyond generation and the app's virtual and legal environment.

Comment: I see it that way too. I feel that the tandem physical *goods -> Google Pay* and *digital goods -> in-app billing* does not tell the whole story. You may buy a digital good like a song, or a movie, that would not apply to the scope of in-app billing. In my eyes, in-app billing applies to digital goods, features or other functionality that provides access to additional features, services or expendables within the scope and boundaries of the service or application.